# IOError While Webscraping Environment Canada With Python

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, web-scraping

For work I am trying to get bulk data from the Environment Canada webpage which has it's own instructions here actually: ftp://ftp.tor.ec.gc.ca/Pub/Get_More_Data_Plus_de_donnees/Readme.txt When I run my code I always get Error 10054; Existing connection forcibly closed by the remote host. As a fairly novice programmer I am wondering if the site just doesn't like my program (I did test the program in it's early stages on provincial government sites and it seemed to retrieve info) or whether I have a specific error in my code that is preventing me from connecting properly. Any suggestions how to proceed are welcome. Thanks

Here is my code; the last try/except block is my attempt to retry the connection after getting the IOError message:

```
import math
import datetime
import sys
import os
import urllib

# out_folder is relative to local directory
# station id is arbitrary; figure this out from the Web site
#   by inspecting the URL of the stations Web page
[station, start_year, end_year, out_folder] = sys.argv[1:5]

print "retrieving data for station "+station+" for years "+start_year+" to "+end_year+" and saving in folder ./"+out_folder+"\n"

# generate filenames and download them
for year in range(int(start_year), int(end_year)+1):
    for month in range(1, 2):

        url = "http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climateData/bulkdata_e.html?format=csv&stationID="+str(station)+"&Year="+str(year)+"&Month="+str(month+1)+"&Day=1&timeframe=2&submit=Download+Data"
        filename = 'stn_'+str(station)+'_'+str(year)+'.csv'
        print 'stn_'+str(station)+'_'+str(year)+'.csv'
        try:
            print "Trying to retrieve data; please hold"
            urllib.urlretrieve(url, out_folder+'\\'+filename)
        except IOError:
            os.mkdir(out_folder)
            print "folder "+out_folder+" does not exist yet, creating it ...\n"
            try:
                print "Trying to retrieve data; please hold"
                urllib.urlretrieve(url, out_folder+'\\'+filename)
            except IOError:
                print "Trying to retrieve data; please hold"
                urllib.urlretrieve(url, out_folder+'\\'+filename)

exit()
```

Additionally if it helps the last line of the traceback is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 476 in readline

data = self._sock.recu(self._rbufsize)

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058932/socket-error-errno-10054

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the needless inquiry; The issue had to do with my own network preventing the connection, I switched to Wifi and the program worked.